# What is the name of this ship?

Tags: far-cry

I have recently replayed FarCry. I just wondered what the name of the freighter is in English. I'm fairly certain it is Macedonian, based on the flag.

Can anyone shed any light on this?
[image: FarCry Freighter]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I don't personally speak the language, so this may be incorrect**

---

I've run this through a few translators and searches and this is what I've come up with:

The first word is defiantly "EVIL" in Macedonian, the second I've had more trouble translating but I believe it's something along the line of "Vessel" or maybe even "Freighter" (This is the Serbian translation of the second word)

I think in essence the ship is called "**Evil Freighter**". A little generic, but I doubt most people would be able to read it or consider what it says.

(In case anyone wants to try this out for themselves, here's the words in text form so you can copy-paste "`ЗОЛ ТЕРЕТЊАК`")

Comment: This seems to make sense in the context of the game, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to this [Ubisoft forum](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/616062-macedonian-flag-on-the-boat-in-stage-COOLER-Forums), the original poster translates it as

> Evil Carrier (Freighter)

The OP is from Macedonia, and has a main concern for why Macedonia has such a ship when the country is landlocked.

The OP states that the wording is from an "irregular Macedonian-Serbian language".

Comment: I wonder if it is a [flag of convenience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_convenience)?

Comment: @Burgi - The game is based in Micronesia, and Marshall Islands is one such common choice for registering a merchant ship.  With Macedonia being landlocked, it is probably more than a coincidence (although you wouldn't be able to say for sure without the designers confirming this is the case).